# Getting Formatted Value in NumericTextBox

Tags: kendo-ui, kendonumerictextbox

When i type the value 123456 in the numeric text box it displays with comma values like 123,456.00

If we access the value it will give me 123456. Now i have a requirement in which i need to get the display value (123,456.00).

Is there any way to get this ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: In a NumericTextBox `format` refers to how the number is present while not having focus. MaskedTextBox might help you with the formatting part while typing, the problem is that then you have to implement `min`, `max`, `spinners`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KendoUI creates a second input for the formatted text with a class of k-formatted-value.  So you could use jQuery to get the value of that input as follows:

```
var numerictextbox = $("#numerictextbox").data("kendoNumericTextBox");
alert(numerictextbox.element.parents(".k-numeric-wrap").find("input.k-formatted-value").val());
```

## **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/AFUtoB)**